# Should I use XsrfProtectedServiceServlet despite its experimental declaration?

Tags: gwt

The [XsrfProtectedServiceServlet](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/XsrfProtectedServiceServlet.java?r=10489) says in its class java-doc description:

> "*EXPERIMENTAL and subject to change. Do not use this in production code.*"

I didn't see that in the first place and I am already using it - though not in production yet. Anyhow, the last change appears to be from 2011 so should I take that serious or not?

Is anybody else using this class already or should I not lay my hands on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used in production and it did not cause any issues for us. Experimental indicates that it is subjected to change. So the way in which servlet should be used may be changed. Then if it changes, you have to change your code as well to make it inline with them.

Saying that we have used that in as early as 2013 when GWT 2.5.1 released and it hasn't given a problem till now.